# How to Insert a value from column to another colum?

Tags: java, sql

i have 2 column Quantity and QuantityOrder, if i am a Customer i want to Order, so in Database the Quantity Column must be subtraction a Value A and QuantityOrder 'll addition a Value A
Example:
 Quantity -1
QuantityOrder +1
i don't know how to write  Insert Statement, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  With the additional information from your comment, this runs on SQL 2012:

First some first aid for your data model:

```
CREATE TABLE [Orders] (
CustomerId INT,
ProductId INT,
Quantity INT,
OrderDate datetime2 default GetDate(),
EnteredBy SYSNAME default original_login() 
)
GO
```

Then the transaction code would be:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @Quantity INT
DECLARE @CustomerId INT
DECLARE @ProductId INT

INSERT INTO Orders (customerId,productId,quantity) 
VALUES (@CustomerId,@ProductId,@Quantity)

UPDATE Customer
SET quantityOrder = QuantityOrder + @Quantity
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId

UPDATE product
SET quantity = quantity - @Quantity
WHERE productId = @ProductId

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I'm Using SQL Sever, i got 2table Product and Customer, i want subtraction from Quantity Column in Product Table and addition to QuantityOrder column in Customer.

Comment: Your data model is not good.  You should really consider getting a new one made by someone with more experience.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm newbie and i have a lot of problems. I'll try to study harder.